# Using cURL within Mule ESB

Tags: curl, mule

Does anyone know a method using Mule Anypoint Studio (community) to invoke cURL commands? I am currently trying to use a groovy script as a wrapper for the cURL but i am not sure if this is possible.

Any guidance would be great.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? What you have tried?

Comment: I need to connect to a HTTPS site and pull some files. I am calling cURL commands from within a Groovy script. At authentication stage using cURL -d with credentials i receive 302 error (document has moved). At this stage i tried to add -L option but cURL only uses credentials at initial location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTTP connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Connector) in order to access web sites or web services using Mule ESB.

Comment: I have explored this method for HTTPS using a keystore but due to the sites setup it doesn't appear possible. I am currently receiving errors from the groovy script that it cannot be run. I am looking to have curl in the build path or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use cURL without a **very** good reason. I'm sure the HTTPS can do almost anything you need SSL related. It's probably worthy to post a different question asking why your HTTPS endpoint is not working.

In the unlikely case the HTTPS connector can't do what you need, you should consider other options that won't require adding extra dependencies to your classpath, like the Java's HttpsURLConnection in a Java component, MEL script or Groovy Script.

Only if nothing of the previous does work, please try adding all the required dependencies to the classpath (I can't provide more specific info as you don't provide your project's configuration in the question).

Comment: Thanks i have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277561/mule-connect-to-https-site-and-pull-files